@prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again. getting this error when deploying to vercel
I was using Prisma for my postgresql db.
Everything was working fine until i started promoting to Vercel.
so whenever i am trying to import Prisma to update something in the code from the prisma.js file i am not getting auto suggestions until i require it like ("@prisma/client")
and if i do so and promote this to production i am getting this error in vercel.
@prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
I have tried everything that is available.
what is the best way to use this please suggest what can i do make this better.
prisma.js
const { PrismaClient } = require("../prisma/generated/client");
let prisma;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}
module.exports = prisma;

package.json
{
  "name": "test-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test backend",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "vercel-build": "prisma generate && prisma db push",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon --env-file=.env index.js",
    "prepare": "prisma generate"
  },
  "author": "Test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.14.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.43.4",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-validator": "^7.1.0",
    "formidable": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "sharp": "^0.33.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.1",
    "prisma": "^5.15.0"
  }
}

vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": [
          "prisma/**",
          "node_modules/.prisma/**",
          "node_modules/@prisma/client/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/index.js"
    }
  ]
}

prisma.schema
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "./generated/client"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL_DEV")
}

Also these are the commands that i use whenever i need to push the db changes
npx prisma migrate dev --name init
npx prisma migrate deploy
npx prisma db push
i believe some of them have the same function but still
